# How can I replace the char '2' in a string with the string "to" in Java?

Tags: java, string, char

I am unsure which version of Java I am using, I am using the CodeHS IDE. I am trying to write a function that "fixes the grammar" in a given string. All the method needs to do is replace all of the 2s with to's. Here is my code:

```
public String useProperGrammar(String text) {
   String fixedString = new String(); 
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) { 
    fixedString += text.charAt(i); 
    if (text.charAt(i) == '2') {

     fixedString = text.substring(0, i) + text.substring(i + 1);

      fixedString += "to"; 
    } 
} return fixedString; }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the string replace function? https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace

Comment: check String#replace or String#replaceAll

Comment: Richard Bamford, will a string replace function work if one is a char and the other is a string? thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Use the `String.replace()` method.

```
        String str = "this is 2";
        str = str.replace('2'+"", "to");
        System.out.println(str);
```

If you append an empty string `""` to the character it will convert it to a string and allow the replace to work.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a character then convert the char into String and use the replace method.

```
    char ch = '2';
    String str = Character.toString(ch);
    str = str.replace('2' + "", "to");
    System.out.println(str);
```